# Add to wishlist button in cart page magento2

Tags: magento2.1.0

In magento2 **ADD TO WISHLIST** button functionality not provided by default on cart page so I want to implement **ADD TO WISHLIST** functionality on cart page how can I do that?

So user can directly add item to wishlist from cart page.

### UPDATE

I have enabled templatepath hint for frontend and I see that on cart page **move_to_wishlist.phtml** file is called from **app/design/frontend/Forever/theme/Magento_Wishlist/templates/cart/item/renderer/actions**

**move_to_wishlist.phtml** file code is below.

```
<?php if ($block->isAllowInCart() && $block->isProductVisibleInSiteVisibility()): ?>
<a href="#"
   data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getMoveFromCartParams(); ?>'
   class="use-ajax action action-towishlist">
    <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Move to Wishlist'); ?></span>
</a>
```

But move to wishlist button is not showing on cart page so I have remove if condition from above code so it's working perfect and showing **move to wishlist** on cart page and working.

So my question is when I remove  **`if ($block->isAllowInCart() && $block->isProductVisibleInSiteVisibility())`** code from **move_to_wishlist.phtml** wishlist button is showing otherwise not so does there issue with block file or core code ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default this functionality already exist in M2. You can check following file

```
1. Magento/Wishlist/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml

2. Magento/Wishlist/view/frontend/templates/cart/item/renderer/actions/move_to_wishlist.phtml
```

In template file, there is an condition like

```
<?php if ($block->isAllowInCart() && $block->isProductVisibleInSiteVisibility()): ?>
```

If this condition is true then you can able to view 'Move to Wishlist' under product image that means [image]

Simple thought is if you login then you can able to view this button in cart page.

[Updated]

Following two function make the 'Move to Wishlist' button visible.

```
#Magento/Wishlist/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer/Actions/MoveToWishlist.php
/**
 * Check whether "add to wishlist" button is allowed in cart
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function isAllowInCart()
{
    return $this->wishlistHelper->isAllowInCart();
}

#Magento/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer/Actions/Generic.php
/**
 * Check if product is visible in site visibility
 *
 * @return bool
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
public function isProductVisibleInSiteVisibility()
{
    return $this->getItem()->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();
}
```

First logic implement in helper class.

```
#Magento/Wishlist/Helper/Data.php

/**
 * Check is allow wishlist action in shopping cart
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function isAllowInCart()
{
    return $this->isAllow() && $this->getCustomer();
}
```

Here **$this->isAllow()** return true if 'wishlist' module output is active(menas this module is not disabled from Admin->Stores->Configuration->Advanced) and and active this module too. **$this->getCustomer()** return true if login.

```
#Magento/Checkout/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer/Actions/Generic.php
/**
 * Check if product is visible in site visibility
 *
 * @return bool
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
public function isProductVisibleInSiteVisibility()
{
    return $this->getItem()->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();
}
```

Comment: Please see my updated question.

Comment: when I remove (comment) **<?php if ($block->isAllowInCart() && $block->isProductVisibleInSiteVisibility()): ?>** wishlist button is showing otherwise not. so can you tell me which condition it is checking and why condition is not true by default?

Comment: One more thing when I open block file **MoveToWishlist.php** on **vendor/magento/module-wishlist/Block/Cart/Item/Renderer/Actions** path but in this file I can't see **isProductVisibleInSiteVisibility()** function and this function is used in template file so I thing that's why if condition is return false.
what do you thing? any suggestion ? any explanation?

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: If this answer help to solve your question, don't forget to accept answer. It's helpful for another.